# Issues when scraping a web page using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have been given a model to run a successful web scraper on a selected website, however, when i alter this to collect data from a second website, it keeps returning as an error. I'm not sure if it is an error in the code or the website is refusing my requests. Could you please look through this and see where my issue lies. Any help hugely appreciated!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

try:
    driver.get("http://www.caiso.com/TodaysOutlook/Pages/supply.aspx") # load the page
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.highcharts-legend-item highcharts-pie-series highcharts-color-0'))) # wait till relevant elements are on the page
except:
     driver.quit() # quit if there was an error getting the page or we've waited 15 seconds and the stats haven't appeared.
stat_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.highcharts-legend-item highcharts-pie-series highcharts-color-0')
for el in stat_elements: 
    print(el.find_element_by_css_selector('b').text)
    print(el.find_element_by_css_selector('br').text)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are passing wrong CSS as it should be like this

```
.highcharts-legend-item.highcharts-pie-series.highcharts-color-0
```

not as you have mentioned.

Then you are closing the browser and then trying to again close it getting the error

```
try:
    driver.get("http://www.caiso.com/TodaysOutlook/Pages/supply.aspx") # load the page
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.highcharts-legend-item.highcharts-pie-series.highcharts-color-0'))) # wait till relevant elements are on the page
except:
     driver.quit()
```

Next on list item you are fetching text

```
print(el.find_element_by_css_selector('b').text)
```

## Debugged Code here:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

try:
    driver.get("http://www.caiso.com/TodaysOutlook/Pages/supply.aspx") # load the page
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.highcharts-legend-item.highcharts-pie-series.highcharts-color-0'))) # wait till relevant elements are on the page
     #driver.quit() # quit if there was an error getting the page or we've waited 15 seconds and the stats haven't appeared.
except TimeoutException:
    pass
finally:
    try:
        stat_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.highcharts-legend-item.highcharts-pie-series.highcharts-color-0')
        for el in stat_elements:
            for i in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('b'):
                print(i.text)
            for i in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('br'):
                print(i.text)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("No Such Element Found")
    driver.quit()
```

I hope this has solved your problem if not then let me know.

Comment: You can also fetch source code of the page using `src_code = driver.page_source` and fed this source code to Beautifulsoup to further process the page.

Comment: Hi Himanshu, thank you very much, this seems to work better, just missing parenthesis for the print statements but that was an easy fix. I do have one query though that you might be able to assist with. I am getting the 'b' element to print out, however, the numerical value linked to 'br' is not coming out. What I am expecting is Renewables 38.96% to be produced, but what I get is Renewables Solar. And searching the code I cannot see the mention of Solar anywhere, do you know if it is possible for me to get that percentage value?

Comment: The percentage is not within the 'br' tag but within the 'span' tag, you have to change 'br' to 'span' in the second find_element_by_tagname.

Comment: Hey Jack i think you need a great amount of help. Shall we connect so that i can help you much better?

Comment: Replacing it with span worked perfectly, thank you very much Frank. I'm going to try and work the rest of it myself but thank you for the offer Himanshu, you have been incredibly helpful

Comment: Hey Jack, if your query is fixed then you can upvote the Answer and close this question.